# java unable to connect to mysql database through netbean IDE

Tags: java, netbeans

All.

I am having a weird problem with Netbeans. for some reasons, the jar file built by netbeans is not able to connect to the mysql server.

However, I can connect to the server using netbeans database interfaces. (like under Services/Databases platter) I can also connect the mysql server using sequel pro. So, I doubt it must be something wrong with network configuration in netbeans.

I am using proxy in netbeans IDE and excluded the mysql server ip.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class JavaApplication11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.101:3306/retailer","root", "newpwd");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }        
        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

Proxy configurations:

```
Proxy Settings:
SOCKS Proxy: 127.0.0.1 Port: 10000
No Proxy Hosts: 192.168.56.101
```

I really hope someone can help me out, thanks a lot.

the stacktraces:

```
Connection Failed! Check output console
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:355)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2461)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at JavaApplication11.main(JavaApplication11.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:129)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:503)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:305)
    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0):

first - check you have mysql jdbc driver jar file inside class path

second - use Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") to load driver in ram